# Chrome Extension: communication between iframe and popup

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension, Which presents the user with an iFrame once the popup window is shown. I wish to invoke javascript function back on the hosting page. Now while I can access the "parent" object (it is not null) I can not invoke any method (like you would do with standard webpage that hosts an iFrame).

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Thanks,
E.

Answer (score 2):

If the iFrame is an extension page, then you can use chrome.extension.getViews 
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getViews

That will get the list of views for that extension, and can manipulate it that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `opener` property to access the window that created the popup.